# How to load a list of dataframes in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, time-series

I have a list that consists of various dataframes (10000), each one of them representing a sequence of 5 frames from a video. So each of the 5 rows has some body points (Rankle_X, Rankle_Y, Lankle_X, Lankle_Y, etc...) of a person in the particular frame.

What I want to do is to build a classifier to detect the movement based on this 5 frames, so I need a time-series network (LSTM, GRU) but I don't know how I should load my data in tensorflow.

The classes that I have in my list are 2 (5000 dataframes from class 1 & 5000 dataframes from class 2)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are trying to model the system as a time-series, you just have to concatenate all the frames [dataframe in your case], and consider every frame as a input to the time series model[LSTM, GRU].[example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series)\

*[NOTE]: while concatenation you have to avoid frame overlapping, and use [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) for DataFrame concat. Also, you have to add extra column to denote `class` of the frame.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!... One question though, do you think is better to denote the class per each dataframe or in each row of the dataframe?...for example, the first dataframe that consists of 5 rows, should it have an extra column with 5 rows that show the class?

Comment: add a new row for a class. there are several reasons backing this. if you create `dataset` and `dataloader` this is mandatory. also, if you want to define `train` and `validation` dataset, all in one dataframe make easier.